# Unable to choose correct picklist value

Tags: validation

I have a problem that in my validation rule. I have a picklist field called "Status". It contains value like,"Progress,Completed,Won,Lost".

If picklist prior value is "progress", then i want choose only completed. Not won and lost.

But I'm not able to choose progress when create a new record. I can able to choose,"won" and "lost" only. What is wrong in my validation rule.

This is my formula:

```
OR( 
AND 
( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Progress"), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Complete")) 
), 
AND 
( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Completed"), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Won")) 
) 
)
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#PRIORVALUE) is a great help here.

> When users create a new record, this function returns the value of the
>   field referenced rather than null. For example, if you create an
>   account named “Acme,” PRIORVALUE(Account.Name) returns Acme.

So when you create a new record and choose "progress"

```
AND 
( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Progress"),NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Complete")) 
)
```

returns true because `PRIORVALUE(Status__c)` equals `"Progress"`

Try changing this formula to something like:

```
AND 
( 
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status__c),"Progress"), NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,"Complete")), NOT(ISNEW()) 
)
```

`ISNEW` function will return true if this is a new record and this validation will nor fire.

Comment: It's working when a new record created with progress. But After edit record I'm not able to choose completed.

Comment: I'm not sure what picklist values you have. In your formula you have "Complete" and "Completed", it might be that you need to change complete to completed in the above example.